# Need help calculating driving gas Costs

Tags: java

Writing the program isn't much of a problem. My trouble is Figuring out the math conversion. I keep getting the wrong output. Thank you.

> Write a program with a car's miles/gallon and gas dollars/gallon (both doubles) as input, and output the gas cost for 10 miles.
>
> > ```
> > Given as input : 20.0   miles/gallon  
> >                  3.1599 dollars/gallon
> >
> > Expected output: 1.58
> > ```

Comment: "I keep getting the wrong output" can you share your code?

Comment: If you just want the formula it would be miles / (miles per gallon) * (dollars per gallon). For your numbers you would have 10 / 20.0 * 3.1599 = 1.57995 which rounds to 1.58

Comment: @MihirKekkar It may be worth mentioning that `10/20` for `int` type would return `0`. Figuring out the reason may be main purpose of this task.

Comment: @Pshemo in the original question the mpg and dollars per gallon are both listed as being doubles. I'll update my comment to show that.

Answer (score 2):

```
dollars       gallons          
--------  x  ---------   x  miles = dollars
gallon        mile
```

You want 20 / 3.1599 * 10 = 1.57995.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use `BigDecimal` to avoid the imprecision of calculations with 'double' as double values are approximations. If you convert the `double` values to `BigDecimal` and then perform the conversion using the utility methods provided by `BigDecimal` you should no longer have any issues with rounding, etc.